# accessing FaceBook API on LocalHost ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, api, localhost

Is there anyway to get Facebook API to work properly completely on LocalHost.  I saw other peoples answers to get two keys - one to www.mydomain/xd_reciever.html  - and one to localhost .

I do not have access to the domain name right now to put my xd_reciever.html up.  I am wondering, is there anyway to get a full working version on localhost without any access to my future domain name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a url shortening service like [bit.ly](http://www.bit.ly/) to shorten localhost into a valid url?

Also, you can change your local hosts file to point a custom domain to localhost as seen here:

> http://blog.amanjain.com/2011/01/using-facebook-connect-on-local-machine/

Comment: no, ill try that,  how do I know what to use in bit.ly ?  it says http://localhost:52686/Default.aspx  , but which ip address do I type in place of that ?